# php 5.6 и mb_функции?

Tags: php

сорри за ньюбский вопрос - несколько лет php не пользовался, а сейчас вот очень срочно пришлось :) Смотрю, в версии 5.6 много всего нового появилось (я 5.3 последнюю застал), в том числе поддержка UTF-8 из коробки. В связи с этим вопрос:

как mb_функции теперь работают?

Например, чем пользоваться strlen или mb_strlen? и т.п. Если поддержка utf-8 нативная, то теперь и strlen должен нормально работать по идее. И есть ли теперь разница между многобайтными функциями и обычными? В документации ничего вроде по этому поводу нет (ну, или я не туда смотрю)

p.s. если кто знает внятный линк на русском в одном месте  (чтобы по кускам не собирать) описывающий изменения с 5.3 по 5.6 - буду очень признателен

update: при гуглении ищется много чего, например:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/136800/
*"Да-да. Больше не придется использовать расширения, вроде multibyte и ему подобных. Все строковые функции отлично понимают юникод."*
Но это похоже слухами и осталось, в документации у mb_* никаких пометок, что они депрекейтед или что-то типа того

Comment: strlen количество байт возвращал и так и надо. Есть iconv_strlen

Answer (score 0):

Никакой нативной поддержки "утф-8" в РНР нет и, увы, в ближайшем будущем не планируется.
Пользоваться можно и той функцией, и другой.
Разница между функциями в том, что многобайтные функции работают с многобайтными кодировками, а однобайтные - с однобайтными.

Comment: Ипатьев - это Ипатьев, а ответ на вопрос - для слабаков, мы лучше тавтологию напишем :)

Comment: "Отныне, input_encoding, output_encoding и internal_encoding, по умолчанию имеют значение "UTF-8"." http://habrahabr.ru/post/233571/ Даже если это и не "нативная поддержка" юникода, то все равно это значит, что все строковые функции по идее его должны поддерживать. Логично? Что тогда происходит c mb_функциями? И утф-8 это многобайтная кодировка, разве нет?

Comment: Это всего-лишь означает, что mb* функции теперь по умолчанию работают с UTF-8, а не (внезапно™) c latin-1 как было раньше.

Comment: artoodetoo, а обычные строковые функции разве с utf-8 не работают, если это теперь дефолтная кодировка? в описании, например, strlen об этом ни слова http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Answer (score 0):

> изменения с версии 5.3 по 5.6

[Вот здесь можно ознакомиться.](http://karmazzin.ru/new-php-syntax-reference)

Comment: спасибо ) да, вот хочется какой-нибудь такой человеческий обзор всего нового и в одном месте )